# Wind Waker's cutscenes freeze in Dolphin Emulator 3.5

Tags: emulation, zelda-wind-waker, dolphin-emulator

I'm currently playing Wind Waker on Dolphin (not using it on Wii), and when I get to one of the first cut scenes (after you get the telescope and go back to your Grandma) it freezes/shows a black screen right when I open the door / trigger it.

I have tried running Tales of Symphonia and have had success with that game so far.

**I guess my question is:** Is there some kind of solution to getting around cut scenes, or some kind of specific settings I might need to run? I am currently running Dolphin 3.5.

**Computer Specs**

- Windows 7 x64
- Intel® Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- 6 GB RAM
- AMD RADEON HD 6450

Comment: Perhaps the image you made is flawed?  If it's freezing, sounds like there's a section that can't be read.

Comment: This could be the issue. I'm hoping that someone else had some problems with graphics/audio settings that caused this for them, although my computer should be able to handle this with ease. I will have to try a new image when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to disable Audio Throttle**

If you have an older version

> you can find it in DSP (Sound settings) and uncheck it.

If you have a newer version

> that option has been moved to the frame limit drop down menu in
>   config. Make sure it's not selected.

[Source](http://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-tloz-wind-waker-blackscreen)

---

If this don't work, download the image again and try it, that can also be the source of your problem.

Comment: Do not plagiarise: http://forums.dolphin-emu.org/archive/index.php?thread-21256.html

Comment: When I say don't plagiarise, I mean you must stop cutting and pasting your answers, not just remember to link to the source. Use your own words, or use quotes. If you never cut-and-paste, you won't accidentally plagiarise as easily.

Comment: Downloading a different image for me worked. Thanks Celta and fbueckert :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [a thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DolphinEmulator/comments/3kk6hl/wind_waker_freezing_at_black_screen_after/?st=J2THRG62&sh=d95ce32a), this was fixed as of Dolphin 5.0.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find exactly when this issue was fixed. It appears to have been fixed sometime between 4.0 and 5.0